# Time format on y axis Primefaces multiaxis LineChart

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, charts

I want to display time on y axis of my chart to HH:mm:ss time format. Now I represent the data in seconds.

Is it possible?

Comment: SS is miliseconds... but why don't you just convert it before putting the date in the model?

Comment: I have a multiaxis chart, displayed months(String) on the x axis and two different value on the y and y2 axis. (x,y) is a bar chart (x,y2) is a line chart.

Chart series need a pair of data (Object, Long)

Answer (score 0):

I used an extender to solve my problem:

xhtml:

```
<p:chart type="line" model="#{myBean.multiAxisChartModel}" style="width:800px;" extender="customFormatter" />
<script type="text/javascript">
    function customFormatter() {
        this.cfg.axes.y2axis.tickOptions.formatter = function(format, value) {
            d = Number(value);
            var h = Math.floor(d / 3600);
            var m = Math.floor(d % 3600 / 60);
            var s = Math.floor(d % 3600 % 60);
            return (h.toString().length == 1 ? ("0" + h) : h) + ":" + (m.toString().length == 1 ? ("0" + m) : m) + ":" + (s.toString().length == 1 ? ("0" + s) : s);
        };
    }
</script>
```

bean:

```
multiAxisChartModel.setExtender("customFormatter");
```

[image]